# Determining the RMS current of diode of a 3 phase rectifier bridge with a filter capacitor and a load

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, three-phase, bridge-rectifier

I would like to know if it possible to determine the RMS current through a diode of a 3 phase rectifier. Here is the simulation. I was looking if I could neglect the effet of the smoothing capacitor but it doesn't seem to be possible so It seems that I have to find a way for calculating this rms current ... I do not find articles given an expresion in function of the load, the input voltage and the smoothing capacitor ? I would be happy if you have some articles on the shelf.

[image]

[image]

Actually it seems relatively possible, if I consider that the voltage on the resistance is relatively constant, so that the resistance can be considered as a current  source when the rectifier does not conduct. I could then find the intercept point between the rectified voltage and the capacitor voltage, so the discharging time ... and so on. I am currently trying !

Have a nice day !

Comment: I think LTSpice should compute RMS for you. In microcap you'd do a transient analysis of RMS(i(D1)) for instance.

Comment: You re right but is a particular case of my converter and I would like to compute it automatically for every current in a whole program that compute all the losses directly for different point of operation in order to trace efficiency and other curve. Finally I hope it will help me to better understand where the converter can be optimized

Comment: _"I would like to know if it possible to determine the RMS current through a diode of a 3 phase rectifier._- Yes, it's possible. We know this because LTspice does it.

Comment: It starts from determining the exact times when the capacitor voltage switches from being charged to being discharged, and that's (1) [very difficult](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4203313/334505) (link on math.ee), and (2) the approximations are [quite inexact](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/576112/95619). So if you want something theoretical you'll get a monster, while something  "close enough" can give you many percents error. In short: use a simulator and trust its results (provided you avoid the [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in%2C_garbage_out) problem).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Well You decouraged me ! It seems really difficult ... Thank you for saving my time ! I will try to do a step command on LTspice for obtaining the RMS current in function of the load - input power asked by the converter

Comment: @Jess I'm sorry for the discouragement, that was not my intent, but in this case a simulator is a far, far less headache compared to the formula you (probably, thank you if so) saw in the other question. But if ou want to go that way, you have my respects, in double. ;-)

Comment: I will not ! "Tempus fugit" but I would have appreciated to try it :) No problem, you help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming EU line input 3ph.

If you can imagine it, you can simulate it. I like Falstad’s.

From this photo for a nominal 10% ripple and default power diodes, you can see all the results on this plot. Crest factor = Peak/Avg but RMS is shown with peak. D.F. of low ESR cap chosen by ESR*C=T time constant.  Surge power for this 333 Vavg, 300Wp load from 246 VRms 50Hz for 10%Vpp/DC I found RC= 54 ms for 3-ph 20ms cycle.

Ppk(in)/Pavg(out)= 1593W/272W= 5.9 crest factor

You can estimate the Rs for the diodes by using the (Vf-0.7)/If. or as I prefer Rs=50%/Pmax component rating. +/-*

If you want more details, this [sim](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCcDFOXEdpgIwHZMGZ8YBWAJkwA5MQiIjraBTAWk0wCgA3ETAFh5BJhy3PgKIA2cN3og8NKRDCQibACYj%20g4b36ZxEEiFUMAZgEMArgBsALmo2ywu0SQkCjpy7baDUecrr6sgEC2IaKGFgk5MJ4eOhwPHKYJNg8RDxkJHhQMFTsAE4gPOKBECX8eE5SPGDibADmxaWO-BWyeJIGbLU5RCnc0SClEJhw4cUA%20qWT2JP4GXg8k0qwYNjiJHDx6QSuK5CYK-Pz0WA9YH0DJCT8IwIxUnjTy2DzcknLIwdHb%20zqN0q1UBYkkhmM5msdgBtwEQgEsL0Bg8kO8XBBWgRmjcoxkckUAmgiXi-TA2W2YyIOSUKi4VU08PpoKkVHk%20Jqhxi2DgZKc2HI4niYDoNPsTMxTKR7ghXmhrXl4rc4M8ULYAHcsdwgpKgucNTotQZEbr1cEys1zSRTe0mf4gfw9WaFdUmY7bcDYa7TSDJaIvQAHJ1S2qjAZUB1sPDYCA6mMhKX5cAXHJwSR6EDkGAZglvEizebiSiJA6wX6RX4nG5wcjKXCkcQ8ohEfn1Ip20KGduugTJrXcDYOW45l7HQRpcQvN5KCvsAD20jwhmwWvIgkM92nUjTEFQy8woyX3GRe4gwhP3ByJ7Y88CLI%20S2GtSgibngz7o3vdA3h3cr5y6b3e9%20BFH9-1Bc551hFpAMWXQInDaRakjYQHSPLN9xAAAlBgAGcAEscJsMwADsAGMGGQ2QFEieAUDohBciwEAAGEzH9MxSLwoiyIooA). permits you display power to determine the efficiency loss of each part with sliders for variables interactively in slow motion or real-time.
[image]

The diode current is approximately a triangle and average Pd is 5% of peak power for 10% ripple.

**Other important results:**
Cap ripple current = 2.3 Arms.
Load ripple current= 0.83 Arms.
Ratio ripple current {C/R}= 2.8 for 10% Vpp/Vavg

This ratio drops cap ripple current ratio to 2:1 for 20% voltage ripple.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to calculate analytically, but it can be approximated.

If you assume each branch is identical, each diode conducts 1/3 of the load current.  The capacitor is certainly affecting the instantaneous current, but it doesn't dissipate any power on its own.

Estimating the DC voltage across the load is fairly straightforward, due to the large amount of smoothing the cap provides.  If you know the load resistance, or the power it's dissipating, you can calculate the RMS current through it.  Divide that by 3, and you should have a reasonable estimate of the RMS current through each diode.

Note that this is based on a resistive load.  Having significant inductance in the load may complicate the situation.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment. I m not sur to have clearly understand what you are saying. You suppose the voltage on the output load is constant as there is a smoothing capacitor ? so the load current is constant as the load and the voltage is contant ? And then you suppose that the current of one diode is equal to the load current divided by 3 ? This is true if there is no smoothing capacitor as you suggest in your first sentence ? You can see the difference on the current in my post from a rectifier with a smoothing capacitor and without smoothing capacitor...

Comment: It clearly affect the value of the RMS current :/ and I cannot neglect it in my case

Comment: You can clearly see the effect of peak power input to diodes and crest factor from my sim.  With 10% ripple cap.  RMS ripple current is not the same as this however. But you can choose this.